# Whats the best way to use ROS to control motors on a simple robot?

Tags: ros, homebrew, rosserial, openni-node, motor-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I've started a new ros project called MockBot at home...
The robot contains the following modules:

Simple lowcost homebrew chassis, which can be build from cheap components.

http://192.166.253.145/BLOG/serendipity/uploads/MockBot-Design-Sheet.pdf

Currently the nodes for Kinect, GPS, Audio and motorcontroller are up and running.

What is the next step in ros design to make these components work together ?
I'd like to create a simple discover-world or ant-brain behaviour...

Problem: what do I need to control the motors or what do I need to make the motorcontrol ros-compatible ?
What can be reused from the turtlebot project ?

Current state: both motor subscribers are listening at /servo1 and /servo2 topics.

Thanks for many tips and tricks from the professionals with experience from practice
Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11482/whats-the-best-way-to-use-ros-to-control-motors-on-a-simple-robot?/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-10-10

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Control of a mobile base is usually done though a [geometry_msgs/Twist message](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html), and the topic is often called "cmd_vel".

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're trying to figure out what speed to drive your motors at (in m/s):

```
left_speed_out = cmd_vel.linear.x - cmd_vel.angular.z*ROBOT_WIDTH/2
right_speed_out = cmd_vel.linear.x + cmd_vel.angular.z*ROBOT_WIDTH/2
```

This assumes that twist.linear.x is your translational speed in m/s, twist.angular.z is your rotational speed in rad/s, and ROBOT_WIDTH is the width between your wheels in m.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3